# How to get current cellular provider in iPhoneXR/iPhone11

Tags: ios

iPhoneXr/iPhone11 have two sim cards, so the variable `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders` will have two values. Is there a way to get the one that is currently in use?

=================

**Update:modified answer from `Mathias` written below:**

```swift
import CoreTelephony

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    if let dataServiceIdentifier = networkInfo.dataServiceIdentifier,
        let allProviders = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders,
        let currentProvider = allProviders[dataServiceIdentifier]
    {
        print("\(currentProvider)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple did not document well this area since iOS 13 but this would work if you consider that the current data provider should be the serviceProvider currently in use :

```
import CoreTelephony

let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let dataServiceIdentifier = networkInfo.dataServiceIdentifier
let currentProvider  = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders![dataServiceIdentifier!]
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I didn't notice this new variable before, thanks